# What is the meaning of error "... object has no attribute ..."?

Tags: python, class, object, methods

Consider:

#### Code

```
class sand:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am a pickle")
        def next(self):
            print("I am a tuner")
```

#### Test and output

```
>>> x = sand()
I am a pickle
>>> x.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    x.next()
AttributeError: 'sand' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no attribute `next` because your indentation is incorrect. Use:

```
class sand:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am a pickle")

    def next(self):
        print("I am a tuner")

x = sand()
x.next()
```

#### Output

```
I am a pickle
I am a tuner
```

Comment: Thanks but it could have just told me that?

Comment: In fairness, it did its best. The original code was perfect valid Python, you just weren't accessing the locally defined method when you thought you were. There's no way the interpreter can know what you meant when what you said was somewhat different.

Answer (score 0):

Please check indentation.

```
>>> class sand:
...   def __init__(self):
...      print("i am a pickle")
...   def next(self):
...      print("I am a tuner")
...
>>> x = sand()
i am a pickle
>>> x.next()
I am a tuner
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined `next` as an inner function inside `__init__`, that's why it is no class attribute of `sand` and therefore you get an `AttributeError`.

Move `next` out of `__init__` and it will work:

```
class sand:
    def __init__(self):
        print("i am a pickle")
    def next(self):
        print("I am a tuner")
```